# How to run instrumentation @SmallTests from terminal?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, instrumentation

I can't run my @SmallTests from terminal. I have created example of my setup and I would like you to point out what am I doing wrong.

1. I am using my own default Runner class which looks like that:

   ```
   public class MyAppTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

       @Override
       public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) 
               throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
           return super.newApplication(cl, MyAppTestApplication.class.getName(), context);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I have set this runner in my gradle:

   ```
   android {
       defaultConfig {
           testInstrumentationRunner "com.MyApp.instrumentation.config.MyAppTestRunner"
       }
       testBuildType 'integrationTest'
   }
   ```
3. I am also using those dependencies:

   ```
   androidTestCompile com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
   androidTestCompile com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
   ```
4. And then I have created simple class with one test case annotated with @SmallTest:

   ```
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.test.filters.SmallTest;
   import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
   import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

   import com.MyApp.a.ui.activity.WelcomeActivity;

   import org.junit.Before;
   import org.junit.Rule;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


   @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
   public class ExampleTestPackage {

       @Rule
       public ActivityTestRule<WelcomeActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
           WelcomeActivity.class, true, false
       );

       @Before
       public void before() {
           activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
       }

       @SmallTest
       public void exampleTest() {
           // some test code
       }
   }
   ```

So this is my setup. According to [documentation of AndroidJUnitRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) which I am using, to run my tests with small annotation I should do something like this:

> Running a specific test size i.e. annotated with SmallTest or
>   MediumTest or LargeTest: adb shell am instrument -w -e size
>   [small|medium|large]
>   com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

So what I do in terminal is:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e size small com.MyApp.debug1.test/com.MyApp.instrumentation.config.MyAppTestRunner
```

But my @SmallTest is not found and the output is:

> Time: 0.001
>
> OK (0 tests)

Furthermore if I start my test class from Android Studio then I can see this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:37)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.buildAndroidRunner(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:83)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:62)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.classes(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:753)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:354)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:260)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
```

Which of course can be fixed if I change my @SmallTest to @Test (import org.junit.Test;)

Am I using wrong classes there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotations `@SmallTest`, `@MediumTest`, etc from `android.support.test.filters` do not replace the `@Test` annotation. The `@Test` annotation is required to signal JUnit that the corresponding method is a test case (http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html).

In your case, this will work:

```
@SmallTest
@Test
public void exampleTest() {
    // some test code
}
```